# How do I get MOUSE_MOVE events in a disabled control (to allow toolTips)?

Tags: apache-flex, events, mouseevent, disabled-input

I actually want to put up a different toolTip if a control is disabled (e.g. to tell the user how to enable it), but the first step is to get MOUSE_MOVE events while the control is disabled, as this is how ToolTipManager starts the tool tip process.

Now, SkinnableComponent uses .mouseEnabled to turn off mouse events when disabled. I'm trying to hack it so it respects the explicit .mouseEnabled, but also eats (or declines to dispatch) all mouse events when disabled for backwards compatibility.

Any ideas? commentary?

UPDATE: I'm going to try and use a skin as a wrapper. The skin will be a UIComponent containing a regular TextInput. I will still have to eat the mouse events when disabled (for compatibility), but if I override `addEventListener()` in the host component (not the skin) and copy references to any listener for the ToolTipManager, I can give it the MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT events.

This allows me to avoid the `UIComponent(this).enabled = value;` hack, which was really bothering me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe Flex: toolTip of a spark component with enabled=false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967887/adobe-flex-tooltip-of-a-spark-component-with-enabled-false)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate.  The question is slightly different; but I think you'll find the solution is the same.

Comment: This one is even closer to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914149/how-to-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-control

Comment: No, I am trying to overcome this (bad?) design. SkinnableComponent should not have use mouseEnabled for this; it should eat the mouse events if it wants to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying 'no' too.  Do the answers to the other two questions not solve your problem?  The whole purpose of a disabled component is that it won't accept input.

Comment: But a disabled control can generate mouse events; stopping mouse events was an arbitrary design decision.

Comment: I don't think it was arbitrary; to me it seems logical.  For example, I think changing the mouse over state of a button that is disabled would confuse users.  Which frameworks/technologies have you used where disabled controls will dispatch mouse events?

Comment: I agree about mouse state, but firing messages is a different.

Informing subscribers about mouse position is useful. If the user clicks a disabled button, I prefer to explicitly tell them why the button is disabled and how they might enable it rather then leave them frustrated and confused.

It's too late now to change the Flex framework: too much code would break. I want to have the component get the events so a disabledToolTip can work, but then eat them so any listeners would not get an unexpected event.